# Connecting Mysql workbench to XAMPP on mac: "Failed to connect"

Tags: macos, xampp, mysql-workbench

I have a XAMPP server running on my mac with ip 192.168.64.2. I would like to connect to this server via mysql workbench.

I searched for the socket path in my.cnf which is `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

In mysql workbench I chose "Local Socket/Pipe" as connection method and entered `192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock` as socket path.

I get this error message:

> Failed to Connect to MySQL using local socket/pipe at "192.168.64.2/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock" with user root

Additional note: Mysql and Apache are running.

I assume the socket-path is wrong, but don't know how I need to change it.

Thanks, Lukas

EDIT: In the `my.cnf` I added `bind-address=0.0.0.0` below `[mysql]`:

```
[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

It still shows me the same error message.

Comment: By default XAMPP's refuses remote connections to database, see https://serverfault.com/questions/52794/how-do-i-allow-remote-access-to-mysql-using-xampp

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Following your link I added the "bind-address" command (see edit in my question) but it is still not working.